# What's wrong with my auto-complete or jedi?

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, jedi

Recently I'm practicing with python and used jedi to provide more convenience. However, there seems a conflict between jedi and auto-complete as follows,

[image]
Before

[image]
After

In one of my .el file under ~/.emacs.d/lisp, as I typed 'def' and wait for auto-complete to display completions, it only display normally when there is no text, otherwise, it displays very weirdly.

As I experimented, this problem exists without relation to the file type.

Comment: solved, it comes from emacs version. Because today I updated emacs to 24.5 on mac. I tried old version of emacs, it becomes normal again.